# Django + WSGI: When is wsgi.py called?

Tags: python, django, apache, settings, mod-wsgi

I deployed my Django-project via Apache2 on a server.

The problem I have is that I have two setting-modules: `settings.py` which are my local development settings and `settingsprod.py` which are my productive settings.

I found the following line in the WSGI.py:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "proj.settings")
```

Is this module only called when using WSGI? And if yes is this a good place to use my production settings like so?

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "proj.settingsprod")
```

For local development I use the development server like so:

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

Does this still defaults to settings.py then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your setup works as expected. Though if you use extra tools like celery, you might need to also specify the `settingsprod` for those setups aswell.

The way I handle such a situation is exactly the other way around: I use `settings.py` for my production settings and have an additional `settings_development.py` that I use for all development tasks. This way I don't have to remember setting the production settings in all production relevant files, but instead simply use the development settings for development like so:

```
python3 manage.py runserver --settings=proj.settings_development
```

If you often use manage.py commands and want to save some time typing, you can make a copy of your `manage.py` e.g. as `manage_dev.py` and change the settings module line like so:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "proj.settings_development")
```

and then call your manage functions with:

```
python3 manage_dev.py runserver
```